# How to add login with amazon in my flutter app?

Tags: flutter, amazon-web-services, dart

I need to add a functionality for login with amazon account in my flutter app.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer [`flutter_lwa`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_lwa) package or [`YouTube`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bN4zRjjSYZ0) tutorial, [`Article`](https://dev.to/aws-builders/building-a-login-function-with-aws-amplify-and-flutter-4667)